# Internal hyperlink bug in FAQ

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

When clicking on *What notation and symbols are commonly used here?* in the right hand side navigation in the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq), I am led to `https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#what-notation-and-symbols-are-commonly-used-here`. This anchor, however, doesn't seem to exist, the page jumps to the section above, titled [*What kind of questions can I ask here?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

I briefly looked into the HTML source, but the anchors don't seem to be produced with a simple `<a name="...">`. It makes sense that this section of the FAQ is broken, because it is unique to english.sx; the other sections appear on all SE sites.

---

Edit:

I think I just understood the source code. For *What kind of questions can I ask here?*, the source code is

```
<h2 id="link-questions" data-title="What can I ask here?">What kind of questions can I
ask here?</h2>
```

For *What notation and symbols are commonly used here?*, however, it's only

```
<h2>What notation and symbols are commonly used here?</h2>
```

The `id`, which I suspect to produce the anchor, is missing.

(Btw, is [programming language syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting) turned off on english.sx?)

Comment: It happens on another SE site as well.

Comment: Yes, syntax highlighting is turned off on English (and most meta sites). The reasons for this should be fairly obvious...

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, even though it wouldn't hurt to enable it for specific languages called like `<!-- language: lang-html -->`, if that's technically possible. Still wouldn't be used here a lot, I guess.

Comment: I believe that section was added by the moderators (as opposed to the other sections which are network-wide), but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Reported separately on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104861/custom-sections-in-faq-dont-work-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part has been added from moderators to the FAQ; mmyers is correct. If you look at the FAQ of other SE sites, you will not notice that section.

The only workaround would be to use HTML instead of Markdown, but the problem is that, as reported in [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) the ID attribute is not allowed, and it would be stripped before rendering (or before saving the FAQ section).